# Configuring my LeddarVu sensor through a ROS package from github

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

https://github.com/mcgill-robotics/ros-leddar. In the github page, I have completed the steps stated in the `READMe.md` file up to the step for running, where I am stuck.

In this step, I am running the command they gave me

```
roslaunch leddar leddar.launch serial:=<serial> frame:=<frame_id> fov:=<fov> range:=<range>
```

inserting the correct parameter values, but I am getting this error:

(EDIT: I actually received this error from using catkin_make in my root folder just now)

```
#### Running command: "make -j8 -l8" in "/home/narayan/catkin_leddar_ws/build"
####
[ 50%] Built target leddar_gencfg
Linking CXX executable /home/narayan/catkin_leddar_ws/devel/lib/leddar/leddar
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lLeddarTech
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lLeddar
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lLeddarC
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [/home/narayan/catkin_leddar_ws/devel/lib/leddar/leddar] Error 1
make[1]: *** [leddar/CMakeFiles/leddar.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
Invoking "make -j8 -l8" failed
```

How can I fix this error? Any more help would be appreciated

Thank you!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/261483/configuring-my-leddarvu-sensor-through-a-ros-package-from-github/) by [narayan](https://answers.ros.org/users/30334/narayan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-05-10

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-05-11**:
This is way too vague. What "trouble" have you been having exactly? Which package "from a github page" are you trying to use? How did you retrieve, build and install it? Which OS is this, exactly? Please update your question by editing it.

**Comment by [narayan](https://answers.ros.org/users/30334/narayan/) on 2017-05-11**:
I have updated it.  I can specify more if needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Have you `source`d the `devel/setup.bash` of the workspace where you compiled the package?

---

Edit:

> ```
> Linking CXX executable /home/narayan/catkin_leddar_ws/devel/lib/leddar/leddar
> ```

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lLeddarTech
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lLeddar
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lLeddarC
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Have you set the environment variable that configures where the LeddarTech driver is located? Under *Compilation* in the readme:

> You **must** compile this package before being able to run it. You can do so by running:
>
> ```
> export LEDDAR_LIB_DIR=/path/to/driver
> ```

```
catkin_make
```

I think if you don't do this linking will not be successful.

In any case: if you keep encountering errors while trying to compile this package I recommend you open an issue on the [issue tracker](https://github.com/mcgill-robotics/ros-leddar/issues) of the package.

This is no longer a problem with ROS per se.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-05-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [narayan](https://answers.ros.org/users/30334/narayan/) on 2017-05-11**:
yes, I have.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-05-11**:
So what is the output of `rospack find leddar`?

**Comment by [narayan](https://answers.ros.org/users/30334/narayan/) on 2017-05-11**:
It is giving me an error, "[rospack] Error: package 'leddar' not found"

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-05-11**:
Ok. So did you build your workspace after cloning the package sources from github? You write that you "have completed the steps stated in the `READMe.md` file". Does that include the `catkin_make` step? Was that successful?

`rospack` not finding your pkg is indicative of a problem here.

**Comment by [narayan](https://answers.ros.org/users/30334/narayan/) on 2017-05-11**:
catkin_make is now successful, but the command "roslaunch leddar leddar.launch serial:..." now has a different error, which is "Linking CXX executable /home/narayan/catkin_leddar_ws/devel/lib/leddar/leddar
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lLeddarTech"

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-05-11**:
Please edit your original question with this new information. Comments are not suited for this.

**Comment by [narayan](https://answers.ros.org/users/30334/narayan/) on 2017-05-11**:
Sorry about that, I have attached the message to my original post